# Using logical operators to subset in a function

Tags: r, function, subset

I'm trying to use a logical operator to subset in a function as follows:

```
iris$Species <- as.character(iris$Species)

mySubsetFunction <- function(df, species){
  dfSubset <- subset(df, Species==species)
  return(dfSubset)
}

mySubsetFunction(iris, species="setosa" | species="virginica")
```

This returns an error:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "mySubsetFunction(iris, species="setosa" | species="
```

How can I set up the arguments of the function to accept logical operators?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You meant to either do:

```
mySubsetFunction <- function(df, species){
    dfSubset <- subset(df, Species %in% species)
    return(dfSubset)
}

mySubsetFunction(iris, c("setosa", "virginica"))
```

(However, use caution when using `subset` inside functions: [Why is `[` better than `subset`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset))

Or use `subset` directly:

```
subset(iris, Species == "setosa" | Species == "virginica"`)
```

or

```
subset(iris, Species %in% c("setosa", "virginica"))
```